# GCP VM stopped responding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

We have a VM server on GCP. Yesterday, the server stopped responding, we could not even SSH into the server, but everything was ok after restarting the server. I am having a look at the metrics and this is what I have noticed:

1. There is no **Memory Utilization** data for that period. Before this, the Memory Utilization was 90%.
2. **Read Through Put**  is quite high; **13 MiB/s**

What could have gone wrong? What else should I consider looking at?

Comment: One of your next steps is to check internal [logs](https://stackify.com/linux-logs/)

Comment: Your question has no details, so only suggestions can be made. 1) Make sure the VM did not run out of disk space. That is a common problem will SSH failing. 2) 90% memory utilization is too high. Try to keep memory utilization below 80%. However, that depends on the services running on the server. 3) If Cloud Logging (Stackdriver) is enabled, review the logs for the reason SSH failed.

Comment: 1. No, the VM did not run out of Disk Space.
2. Yes, we will try to keep the memory utilization low, but can we know what caused the memory to go high?
3. There are no traces in Cloud Logging as to what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harith:

The applications processes running in your VM consumed the totality of the memory assigned to the VM.
Analyze each application hosted on the VM and evaluate its MTRs (Minimal Technical Requirements) and the actual work load that each one represent, this in order to estimate if the memory amount assigned is enough to support that load.
Consult log entries if available on those applications to see if they can reveal the consumption level just after the unresponsive condition.
Consider [changing the machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) if you have to increase any resource capcity assigned to your vm.

If the resource consumption of your applications running on your VM will be very variable, you will need consider the implementation of [autoscaling groups of instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler).